# C# Settings.settings displays as XML not as Grid View

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Windows Form Application with user settings that can be used to populate text boxes at run time. I know that I can create the user settings from the Solution Explorer by double-clicking on "Settings.settings" under the project Properties.

When I double-click on Settings.settings it opens up as an XML document and not a grid view. I expect to see something as shown in the video link below, not an XML file.

https://youtu.be/tIOWI0JBFkg?t=29

For reference, the XML file contains the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Name="(Default)" />
  </Profiles>
  <Settings />
</SettingsFile>
```

**Is there a Visual Studio setting I can change to get the settings designer to show up as a grid view and not as an XML document?**

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.3 and .NET Framework 4.8.03752.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the file,

select "Open With",

Click "Settings Designer" from the list (just click to select, don't double click)

Click the "Set as Default" button on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Right click Settings.settings -> Open With -> Set as Default `Managed Resources Editor`

[image]
[image]